# Не работает скролл в Column (jetpack compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я пытаюсь сделать такой лейаут:

[image]

Содержимое лейаута: наверху картинка с фиксированным размером, внизу Column с фоном с закруглениями. Эта Column серым фоном занимает всю оставшуюся часть экрана, даже если содержимого мало. Внизу кнопка. Это всё скроллится, кроме кнопки - она всегда прилипает к нижней части экрана.

Хоть лейаут и кажется простым, с ним есть проблема. Для того, чтобы нижний лейаут занял оставшуюся часть экрана, у Column я прописал `.weight(1f)`. Но в таком случае исчезает возможность скроллить. И наоборот, без этого модифаера или с модифаером `.fillMaxHeight()` скролл работает, но тогда лейаут занимает только часть экрана:

[image]

Есть предположение, что это связано с тем, что для скролла родителю нужно знать размеры вложенных лейаутов, а при `.weight(1f)` он не знает. Но могу ошибаться. Подскажите плз, что использовать, чтобы всё-таки построить такой лейаут?

```
    @Composable
fun TestCompose(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = Color.White),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                .weight(1f)
        ) {

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                painter = painterResource(id = drawable.check_status_icon),
                contentDescription = null
            )

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f) // Этот модифаер позвляет серой заливке дойти до низа экрана, но взамен отключает скролл. И наоборот, если его нет или вместо него .fillMaxHeight(), то скролл есть, но лейаут не доходит до низа
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                // Здесь несколько лейаутов в Column, для простоты оставил один текст
                Text(text = text)
                // AnotherLayout()
            }

        }


        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            onClick = {}){
            Text("Go to main", fontSize = 25.sp)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая проблема. Самое простое решение - не использовать `weight(1f)`, а использовать `fillMaxSize()`, а для этого придется не класть кнопку в Column, а сделать Box, куда положить Column со скроллом и кнопку поверх прижать к низу. Но тогда возникает вторая проблема - контент со скроллом будет за кнопкой. И вам нужно указать нижний padding для контейнера скролла чтобы вытащить его из-за кнопки.. А его либо забить константу, либо нужно `Modifier.onSizeChanged`, который сделает дополнительную рекомпозицию (а то и не одну), и вообще рекомендуется только для диагностики.

Правильно задать жесткий размер скроллируемой области, а для этого уже нужен подход через "слоты", то есть `SubcomposeLayout`
Я не особо его знаю, поэтому попроще.

```
@Composable
fun MyLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    bottomContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    SubcomposeLayout(modifier = modifier) { constraints: Constraints ->
        // тут кнопка определяет свой размер. По ширине пусть берет все, а по высоте не более ей нужного
        val bottomPlaceable: Placeable = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Bottom, bottomContent).map {
            it.measure(Constraints(maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth))
        }.first()

        // а тут основной контент определяет свой размер. Из общей высоты вычитаем кнопку и пусть умещается
        val contentPlaceable: Placeable = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Main, content).map {
            it.measure(
                Constraints(
                    maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                    maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight - bottomPlaceable.height
                )
            )
        }.first()

        // размещаем
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            contentPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            bottomPlaceable.placeRelative(0, contentPlaceable.height)
        }
    }
}

enum class SlotsEnum {
    Main,
    Bottom
}
```

и используем

```
@Composable
fun TestCompose() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    MyLayout(
        content = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(state = scrollState)) {
                Spacer( // ака картинка
                    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp).align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                )
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp))
                        .background(Color.LightGray)
                ) {
                    repeat(40) {
                        Text(text = "Android $it")
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        bottomContent = {
            Button(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                onClick = {}) {
                Text("Go to main", fontSize = 25.sp)
            }
        })
}
```